# how to install a second server of mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.6, mariadb-10.1

I have a server where cpanel is installed (it includes mysql 5, php). What I need is to install a second database server mariadb 10.1.20. I tried through:

```
yum install MariaDB-10.1.20-centos6-x86_64-common.rpm
```

But it shows me conflicts like

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-server-5.6.38-1.cp1162.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.20-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-server-5.6.38-1.cp1162.x86_64
```

What can I do for this case?

Comment: See if `yum` has some options.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably run into more conflicts than just what is listed in the question, e.g. TCP port, datadir, /etc/my.cnf, as well as maybe pid and socket. I think these configuration issues can be overcome by using different settings (MariaDB-specific sections in the .cnf files).

I'm not sure whether installing MariaDB from packages alongside a standard installation of MySQL (from packages) is feasible. `rpm` has an option `--relocate OLDPATH=NEWPATH` and `--prefix NEWPATH` which allows you to set a non-standard install path for rpms marked as relocatable. Not all rpms are reloatable.

However, see [Installing MariaDB alongside MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/) (mariadb.com) which talks about installing the compiled binary distribution of MariaDB 5.5 from source code alongside an existing installation of MySQL. This is also the approach used by tools like [dbdeployer](https://www.dbdeployer.com/).

See also [Running Multiple MySQL Instances on One Machine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-servers.html) (mysql.com) which talks about installing multiple MySQL instances on the same server. This may or may not be useful.

One relatively low-effort solution could be to install MariaDB in a Docker container. See e.g. [MariaDB and Docker use cases, Part 1](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-and-docker-use-cases-part-1):

> **Docker use case #1: Multi Tenancy**
>
> A common use case for MariaDB and Docker is running several instances of MariaDB on the same physical hosts.