# Multiple versions of mysql / mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am running 10.3.18-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server but for one application it require I run mysql 5.7, so I am installed that to run under another port which works fine.

However for the software that requires mysql 5.7 I cannot seem to pass this as my mysql client version still shows up as mariadb's 5.5 mysql client.

This is my.cnf for the mysql 5.7 version

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3307
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock


[mysqld]
port = 3307
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
datadir = /var/lib/mysql2
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql2/mysqld2.pid
```

is there someway to specify what mysql client binary I can run ? I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql -V
/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 99552
Server version: 5.5.5-10.3.18-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
```

Comment: Did `...bin/mysql` generate that message including `Server version: 5.5.5-10.3.18-MariaDB`?  Strange.

Comment: yes and my thoughts as well, but realize i must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Specify ini-file for mysql client explicitly.

Comment: Does the software that require MySQL 5.7 need the `mysql` command-line client? That sounds a bit unusual. Which software is this?

Comment: The software is akeneo community edition, and due to the way they work with json then mariadb is not compatible.  I think their test looks for the client version as that is the only place I can see where mysql 5.5 is reported as the version.

Comment: @vbird The server also reports 5.5, so it could be reading it from there. I think most software that accesses MySQL/MariaDB databases will use the client libraries, but not the `mysql` binary.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql` in your last code snippet, that is obviously your MySQL 5.7 `mysql` command-line client, but the output shows it's connecting to your MariaDB server:

```
Server version: 5.5.5-10.3.18-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
```

If you want it to connect to your MySQL 5.7 server, then you need to specify the non-default port or socket and maybe other credentials like the database user and password (if you have created that), e.g. one of these commands:

```
/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql -P3307
/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql -uroot -p -P3307
/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql -S/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
```

For reference, see also [my answer to "how to install a second server of mariadb"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202826/94242).

Comment: The last one works

 /usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql -S /var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 107
Server version: 5.7.27-log Source distribution

the others do not 
 /usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql -P3307
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 112087
Server version: 5.5.5-10.3.18-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server

Comment: @vbird In that case it seems MariaDB is actually running on port 3307.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, lack of experience with multiple versions added to my issues as well assuming that I was running the client of the installed mysql version 5.7 would have me use that version was wrong as it would still load the wrong my.cnf which

/usr/local/mysql2/bin/mysql  -u grshop_grpim -p --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options" showed me.

I also think I needed to bind to the 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but cannot verify that.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```